# Can't connect to Linksys E2000 router admin interface: Connection refused

Tags: router

I am trying to connect to our router on 192.168.1.1 (correct IP) directly plugged in via Ethernet cable.

Connection via Firefox simply gives the `can't establish a connection to the server` error.

When I try a `WGET` command from our `CentOS` machine, I recieve the error `...failed: Connection refused.`

Can anyone tell me why the router might be refusing connections to it's web interface?

Cheers

Comment: new router? have you ever been able to connect to the interface before? Reset to factory defaults if you can start from scratch. You can usually do that via a special button.

Comment: Did you plug the Ethernet cable into the LAN or the WAN side? Sane defaults are to only allow configuration from the LAN side.

Comment: Is the computer you're trying to reach the router from in the same network?  same mask?  All the factory resets in the world won't help if you're on a different network :)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible the router has been configured to disable the web interface. This can be done in a number of ways, some of which may not apply to your particular model.

1. Switch to only allow admin via HTTPS.
2. Restrict the ip addresses of the computers that are allowed to access the admin page.
3. Disable admin page altogether.

For systems that do allow option 3 there must be another way of configuring the router. This could be via some special software program (which quite often is windows only) or by using telnet or by connecting the computer directly to a machine using a serial lead and using hyperterminal.

Of course you should always check that your browser isn't just blocking a popup that is asking for the username and password.

Comment: I had this same issue and it turned out I had turned on #1 (HTTPS only) and forgotten about this. It got so secure, it kept me out :)

Answer (score 0):

> Reset – There are two (2) ways to reset the Linksys E2000 to its
>   factory defaults.  Either press and hold the Reset button for
>   approximately five (5) seconds, or restore the defaults from the
>   Administration > Factory Defaults screen in the Linksys E2000
>   web-based setup page.
>
> NOTE:  After resetting the router, your Internet and wireless
>   configuration will be erased.  To know how to reinstall the router,
>   click [here](http://www6.nohold.net/Cisco2/ukp.aspx?pid=80&vw=1&articleid=21463).
>
> QUICK TIP:  To log in to the router’s web-based setup page, just leave
>   the User name blank then enter the default Password “admin”.

Cisco Knowledgebase: [Getting to know your...](http://www6.nohold.net/Cisco2/ukp.aspx?pid=80&app=vw&vw=1&login=1&json=1&docid=e2a9d412b9fd41748f411a96c1e2fbd3_21478.xml)